# Conditional Check of Empty or Null values prior to my SQL commit

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

How can I accomplish a conditional check for Null or empty values prior to my SQL insert command?

Example shows the insertion of a test count (8) but in production I will have a much larger number.

```
respuesta = MsgBox("código del documento " & codigo & " Seguro que ya desea guardar?", vbOKCancel)
If respuesta = vbOK Then
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblDocumentos (docCodigo,docDescripcion, docElaboro,docAprobo,docReviso,docURevision)values (txtcod,txtdesdoc,txtela,txtapr,txtrev,txtultrev)"
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblProcedimientos (codDocumento,descripcion)values (txtcod,txtpro1)"
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblProcedimientos (documento,descripcion)values (txtcod,txtpro2)"
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblProcedimientos (documento,descripcion)values (txtcod,txtpro3)"
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblProcedimientos (documento,descripcion)values (txtcod,txtpro4)"
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblProcedimientos (documento,descripcion)values (txtcod,txtpro5)"
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblProcedimientos (documento,descripcion)values (txtcod,txtpro6)"
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblProcedimientos (documento,descripcion)values (txtcod,txtpro7)"
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblProcedimientos (documento,descripcion)values (txtcod,txtpro8)"
codigo = depto & area & tdoc
Me.txtcod.Value = codigo

MsgBox "Documento creado"
clear
```

Comment: I do believe this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop:

```
For i = 1 To 100
    If Not IsNull(Me.Controls("txtpro" & CStr(i)).Value) Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblProcedimientos (documento,descripcion) Values ('" & Me!txtcod.Value & "','" & Me.Controls("txtpro" & CStr(i)).Value & "')"
    End If
Next
```